# CSS How to place a submit button on a new line?

Tags: css, input, newline, submit

How can I place an input type=submit on a new line following a text area element?

without using a br tag or a div, ideally I like to do it using css.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
<textarea></textarea><input type="submit" class="submitbutton">


.submitbutton{
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can display it as a block-level element with `display:block`. With CSS 2 you can use this rule:

```
input[type=submit] {
    display: block
}
```

Comment: is this not going to stretch the button, to the whole available width?

Comment: @John: No, not as far as I know.

Comment: Your solution works for text boxes and list boxes, but for some reason it does not work with maps. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62354598/putting-submit-button-at-the-bottom-of-the-form