# Creating HTML buttons dynamically using HTML, CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wish to dynamically add a button on a html form so that a user can upload multiple files when filling-in the form. The css design is both elastic and fluid and the intention is that whenever a user clicks on the "add file" link, a new button is added to allow the user to browse for the file, add it and finally upload it. The buttons should appear on the main content area of the page and should not overflow outside the footer area and should be rendered vertically with each button appearing on a newline. The code below does exactly that. This question is very much related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038369/css-how-to-place-a-submit-button-on-a-new-line/2038374#2038374) but with a twist of the css (design) requirements.

```js
    
        function myFunction() {
 var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
 var text = document.createTextNode("Browse..");
 btn.appendChild(text);
 var newbutton = document.getElementById("button"); //new div button   element introduced on html.
   document.body.insertBefore(btn,newbutton);//insert before method
 
}
```

```css
    /*Mailu*/
        div {
     padding: 1px 0;
       }
        #header {
         background: #DDDDDD;
         
        }
    
        #footer {
         clear: both;
         background: #DDDDDD;
        }
    /*add css as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2038374/2941758*/
        button{display:block;}
```

```html
    
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
        <link href="button.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <div id = "header">
        <p>Home</p>
        </div>
    
    
        <p>Upload file.</p>
        First name: <input type = "text" name = "Firstname"><p>
        <div id = "button"> <!--added div button on html-->
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick= "myFunction()" > Add file</a>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"><p>footer</p>
    
        </div>
    
    
    
        </body>
        </html>
```

```
  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943352/dynamically-create-element-but-use-a-href-instead-of-a-button-onclick
```

Comment: You're mixing some concepts here. No element is "within" the CSS, only rules about the display of your document. If something doesn't have this rule applied, then the rule target ("css selector") is specified incorrectly. (hint: # is for specifying target id in CSS)

Comment: _"outside the CSS"_? There is no such thing...

Comment: @doldt even if i add the elements within the css, the results remain the same

Comment: @AlexMaina, as I said, you cant add elements to the css. Only *selectors* which will *match* certain elements.

Comment: I have edited the css above and included id div @doldt

Comment: After editing the code above, the javascript puts all the buttons before the footer. How can i now make the buttons appear on a new line without them showing after the footer?

Comment: @Cerbus... i have found an answer. Please open up the question from "on hold" so that i can answer it

Comment: The answer to this problem lies here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2038374/2941758

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
#button {
```

With:

```
button {
```

The `#` is an `id` selector, meaning it will apply the styles to the element that has `id="button"`.

If you leave out the `#`, it will match all `<button>` elements.

Comment: @Cerbrus...done that. result remains the same

Comment: Sure, but the rule _is_ now applied to your dynamically created button. If the `margin-left` isn't changing, it's because it already was `auto`. What exactly are you trying to do to that button?

Comment: I'm trying to upload a file with it. I need it to fall within the CSS. I have editd the CSS above and ncluded id div. @Cerbrus

Comment: What do you mean with _"I need it to fall within the CSS"_?

Comment: I want the button to appear before the footer not after

Comment: Oooooooh. That's a _completely_ different question. This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258185/javascript-append-child-after-element

Comment: @Cerbus i have found a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038369/css-how-to-place-a-submit-button-on-a-new-line/2038374#2038374...thanks for the support