# Putting Submit button at the bottom of the form

Tags: html, css, django, django-forms

[image]

I want the submit button to be at the bottom of the form. I have tried using `<div>`, `<div float="left">`, `<div float="right">`, `<br>` and `<span>`. So far the only solution I have come up with is to repeat `<br>` multiple times which is a messy solution and one that is only compatible on laptops the same size as mine.

```
 <form method="post" action="">
      {% csrf_token %}

      {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
{{ hidden }}
{% endfor %}

<div float="left">
{# Include the visible fields #}
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <br class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} 
</br>


        {{ field }}

{% endfor %}

      </div>
      <div float="right"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>



    </form>
```

**Update**
I tried Gumbos suggestion ([CSS How to place a submit button on a new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038369/css-how-to-place-a-submit-button-on-a-new-line)). But there is something about the map which is making the submit button act strangely. For testing purposes I created a submit button after every field. Gumbos suggestion worked fine for text boxes and list boxes. But not maps.

[image]

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


<html>



<head>
<style>
  input[type=submit] {display: block}
</style>
{{ form.media }}



</head>



 <body>

    <form method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
        {{ hidden }}
        {% endfor %}

        {# Include the visible fields #}
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}

        <br class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} 
        </br>
        {{ field }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        {% endfor %}
  </form>



</body>

</html>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Don't use a `float` on the map. This causes the `div` not to act like a `block` object and push the next div down the page. If you need the float for some reason (its not apparent from your code). Remember to [clear your floats](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_clearfix.asp) so the other elements behave normally.

Comment: I have put an update at the bottom of my post. It is something about the map which is making the submit button act strangely.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the `float` and change `br` into `div`

```
<form method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}

  {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
  {{ hidden }}
  {% endfor %}

  <div>
    {# Include the visible fields #}
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}

    <div className="fieldWrapper">
      {{ field.errors }}
      {{ field.label_tag }}
    </div>

    {{ field }}

    {% endfor %}

  </div>
  <div><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: I have put an update at the bottom of my post. It is something about the map which is making the submit button act strangely.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post [Overwrite float:left property in span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62456842/overwrite-floatleft-property-in-span/62456967#62456967) for the answer.

With Bens help I was able to overwrite some of the default CSS.