# Overwrite float:left property in span

Tags: html, css, django

I want the submit button to appear below the map. I can achieve this by deactivating float:left. How could I achieve this?

I tried overwriting the properties of `<Span>`.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      input[type=submit] {display: block}
  span {float:none}


</style>
{{ form.media }}


</head>
  <body>
```

And modifying the properties of the widget. Neither worked.

```
widgets = {
    'Location':  OsmPointWidget(attrs={
      'map_width': 300, 
      'map_height': 300,
      'style':'float:none'}),
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using custom css (in a custom css file or in the header), you can override the `float:left` by adding:

```
#id_Location_span_map {
  float: none!important;
}
```